# Load more data for Gridview using ansyntask makes record disorder

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-gridview

I have an activity that contains 1 GridView and load 10 more records from server whenever Onscroll fired.

```
`   @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
            int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        long lastVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
        int i = (totalItemCount) % AppGlobal.ROWS; //AppGlobal.ROWS = 10
        if(i == 0 && lastVisibleItem == totalItemCount){
            InitGrid(++currentPage );
        }
    }

    public void InitGrid(int page){
        ArrayList<absDataItem> items = new ArrayList<absDataItem>();
        try {
            if(AppGlobal.isInternetConnected)
                items = new LoadGridTask().execute("publishcontent", mCategory, page * AppGlobal.ROWS, AppGlobal.ROWS).get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            Log.v(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.v(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }

        if(items.size()>0){
            if(mAdapter==null) 
                mAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(AppGlobal.ApplicationContext);
            mAdapter.addAll(items);

            if(mGridView.getAdapter()==null){
                mGridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            }else{
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
`
```

Everything run OK except at the first time when the activity create, OnScroll event fire twice and so the InitGrid function runs 2 times with currentPage is 0 and 1. Because the task LoadGridTask() in an asynctask so, most of time, the InitGrid(1) finish before InitGrid(0) so the record 11-20 show before record 1-10, that make my records not in desired order.

How can I fix this? Thank in advanced!

Comment: Sorry if it take your time, I found my problem, at last. the code should be InitGrid( currentPage++ );